# Refreshing JTextArea with new values

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I am new to java.

I have a project from college where I have to make entries to txt file through 2 `JTextField` boxes and 1 `JButton` (save) which will display the entries in `JTextArea`.  I am able to make entries in txt file successfully. But how to refresh `JTextArea` at run-time to display the new entries I recently made?

Thanks for helps:
below is my code:

```
try {
            //use buffering, reading one line at a time
            //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("RokFile.txt"));
            try {
                String line = null; //not declared within while loop

                while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
                    jTextArea1.append(line+"\n");
                }
            }
            finally {
                input.close();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Let me know if its correct?
Thanks

Comment: Please add the [tag:homework] tag to homework questions.

Comment: Does it work? If it works then I would say that it's correct.

Comment: Its not working, It wont display the new entries as soon as i make in JTextfields.

Comment: You shouldn't have a need to refresh the JTextArea, it should be refreshing itself when you add text. How were you adding text before you used `append()` and are sure you're adding text to the JTextArea that is on the JFrame?

Answer (score 1):

[`JTextArea.append`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) ought to suffice. This method is thread-safe and will update the text area's content automatically.

This answer assumes that you already have the EventListeners configured.

Comment: Hi, Could you let me know if above code(question updated) is correct?

Comment: JTextArea.append isn't actually thread safe: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4765383

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods,

1. If you want to display the content as soon as you write in `jTextField`(fairly attainable), you can do it this way, in the `FocusLost` event of `jTextField`, give something like `jTextArea.setText(jTextField.getText())`
   Note, that this is fairly near to what you want.(also,NOT perfect code)
2. If you want to display the contents when you click `save` , the above code, `jTextArea.setText(jTextField.getText())` may be given in the event handler of the `save` button.